Uniformly continuous function sequence with uniform convergency
Is it possible to say if  $X\subset \mathbb{R}$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f_n :X \to \mathbb{R}$ are uniformly continuous and $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ then $(f_n)$ is uniformly equicontinuous function sequence?
Here is my try:
Let $\varepsilon >0$ is given.
(1) By uniform convergency there exists $n_0(\varepsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ and for all $x\in X$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon /3$.
(2) By uniform limit of uniform continuous functions is $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta_0(\varepsilon)>0$ such that for all $x,y\in X$ with $|x-y|<\delta_0$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/3$.
(3) By uniformly continuity of functions, there exists $\delta_n (\varepsilon)$ such that for all $x,y \in X$ with $|x-y|<\delta_n$ we have $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\varepsilon /3$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
(In this case choice of  $\delta= \min \{\delta_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ could be wrong because there could be no minimum for this set)
If we choose $\delta=\min \{\delta_0, \delta_1, \cdots , \delta_{n_0 -1} \}$ then for all $x,y \in X$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ we have
$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq |f_n(x)- f(x)|+|f(x) - f(y)|+ |f(y)-f_n(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon$.
I think that I didn't use the (3) effectively (just use for only $f$ is uniformly continuous). With this respective my proof is enough? Thanks in advance for your help

(3) is not needed. Such a property with $\delta_n$ depending on $n$ is not at all useful.

@geetha290krm I also think that it is not useful, so is my proof is enough?

Yes, your proof is fine.
